# Render, Partial, View. what should i put in my template?

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have an application where i wish to create a user profile widget. The widget will sit in the navbar in the application template. the widget will look like a login button that pops up a modal login dialog or a dropdown menu that contains links to various user related functions/routes.

the logic for the widget is so far this:

```
{{#if 'user.loggedIn'}}
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"/> {{user.username}}</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>{{#link-to "profile" user}}Profile{{/link-to}}</li>
    <li>{{#link-to "logoff" user}}Logout{{/link-to}}</li>
</ul>
{{else}}
    <button class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn" data-target="#loginModal" data-toggle="modal">Login</button>
{{/if}}
```

I wish to have a controller handle the login functions and calling the modal prompt:

```
App.UserController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    loggedIn: Em.computed.readOnly('model.loggedIn'),
    username: '',
    password: '',
    showLoginModal: function(){
        Em.$("#loginModal").modal();
    },
    hideLoginModal: function() {
        Em.$("#loginModal").modal('hide');
    },
    login: function() {
        var username = this.get('username'),
            success = true; //attempt a login
        console.log('logging in as' + username);
        if(success) {
            this.send('hideLoginModal');
            this.set('user.loggedIn', true);
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

So my question is, what is the best way to get this component/view/partial into the application template using the UserController for the widget?

I'm very new to ember so please be nice :).

Comment: I would not use an UserController, instead I would put this logic into the ApplicationController. You would not need other Controller/Route...  Regarding your modal logic  http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/modal-views-can-we-agree-on-a-best-practice/707

Comment: Thanks for directing me to the modal logic forum. This seems to be a highly opinionated topic. I like the idea of manually inserting the modal, however i need to work on my ember fu before I get into manually creating and inserting views to the hierachy.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a component for the view, and handle the login logic in the ApplicationController and the UserModel.

But actually, there are multiple ways to solve that problem! U could also do it directly in the applicationTemplate.

But: U should not use a normal view or partitial! Mostly u should use a component instead!

The render helper IS an option, if u need the View/Controller pattern, and if its not clearly seperated!

Generall:
If u can seperate it, you should. And then u should use a component.

Comment: can you bind controller/model properties to elements within the components? I am hoping to create a button that displays a loading symbol whilst attempting a login, displays a cross when it fails and a success tick when it succeeds. I want to make this button a reusable component but have not yet wrapped my head around how i can 'control' this component's different states.